# custom validation markup in Rails(3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm trying to accomplish the following mark-up for all my form elements

```
<div class="input-container">
  <label>Topic Title</label>
  <div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="textarea-container">
  <label>Post</label>
  <div class="textarea-holder">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

invalid fields mark-up:

```
<div class="input-container alert">
  <label>Topic Title</label>
  <div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="textarea-container alert">
  <label>Post</label>
  <div class="textarea-holder">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's my current haml markup:

```
.input-container
  = f.label :title, 'Topic Title'
  .input-holder
    = f.text_field :title
.textarea-container
  = f.label :body, 'Post'
  .textarea-holder
    = f.text_area(:body, :size => "60x10")
```

Now what would I need to do if I want the container divs to have the alert class when a field in my form is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same thing but unfortunately haven't figured out a clean way to handle it.

You can override ActionView::Base.field_error_proc, but that doesn't help with the enclosing elements.

It can be done manually by checking errors on each field ('post.errors['body'].nil?') and outputting your alert class conditionally.

The next step could be extracting the logic into a view helper, and perhaps some further abstraction after that.

But it would still be nice to do this in a more automated, Rails-y fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to use either the **[formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)** or **[simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)** gems which out of the box support highlighting an individual invalid field.

I'm almost certain they do this by changing the CSS class on the field or its container, which you could also hook into in your stylesheets.

Comment: Do they style the container, or only the input? Because that's the key issue. I took a quick look at each, because I'm interested in the answer, but couldn't tell (not that I want to add yet another gem to my projects ;).

Comment: Even if they style the container, you should be able to use a CSS selector to find the underlying field: `.alert input` or whatever class they actually use.

Comment: Nah, I mean I'd like to be able to style a containing element (see my answer above), but the usually cited technique of overriding ActionView::Base.field_error_proc doesn't give you the containing element, only the affected input.

Comment: I checked both gems and I think @TK-421 is right. I'm also looking to add a class to the containing element.

Comment: And it can be done as discussed above, but in a way that seems to work against the framework instead of with it. I'm trying to get there, and have an auto-labeling form builder (via a view helper, another frequently cited example), but it seems the custom form builder would need to know about the model's error collection in order to add per-field error styles, which doesn't feel quite right.